# Get row values from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm following this guide:
https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/retrieving-data-from-mysql-via-python/

This is the code:

```
...
cursor.execute ("SELECT X,Y,Z FROM tab_a")

# fetch all of the rows from the query
data = cursor.fetchall()

# print the rows
for row in data :
   print row[0]
```

This doesn't work. It says:

```
print row[0]
KeyError: 0
```

if I change it to:

```
for row in data :
   print row
```

it gives:

```
 {'X: '120', 'Y': '0', 'Z': '730'}
```

This is the correct data but I want it to print only `120` not the whole list.

How do I do that?

Comment: You would `print(row["X"])` but where is the dict coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you. This worked.

Comment: No worries, does `MySQLdb` return a dict by default? With the mysql.connector you have to `connection.cursor(dictionary=True)`

Comment: With mysql.connector you can `connection.cursor(dictionary=True)` or `connection.cursor(named_tuple=True)` for a named tuples, I am surprised that your code returns a dict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you are correct I added: cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)` means you get a dict returned in place of the *tuples* you would normally get so you need to access by key:

```
for row in data:
    print(row["X"])
```